# CSS hide/show using only in-line CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

A particular web editor only allows in-line css and no javascript.

I would like to make a minimal show/hide section:

```
<div>
    <p id="question"><a href="#answer">What do you call a fish with no eyes</a></p>
    <p id="answer" style="visibility:hidden">Fsssssssh</p>
</div>
```

Is there any solution? - I.E. compatible.

Comment: You need to expand on what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean show and hide using only inline css? Once you set the inline css, how are you going to change since you can't use js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, **no**.

While it's entirely possible to achieve such a system (for multiple questions and answers) without any JavaScript whatsoever, it's not possible to do it purely inline. This is because you can't target pseudo-elements inline.

And even with you current HTML structure this would **still** be impossible, as there is no child selector in CSS (though a **[`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)** pseudo-selector has been drafted).

In addition to this, it's also worth noting that inline CSS has a higher **[level of specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** than stylesheets; a stylesheet rule cannot override inline CSS unless you make use of an `!important` declaration.

Assuming you are change your HTML, this can be achieved with a combination of the **[`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)** pseudo-selector, the **[adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** and the `!important` declaration, as can be seen in the following:

```css
#question:focus + #answer {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="question" href="#">What do you call a fish with no eyes</a>
  <p id="answer" style="visibility:hidden">Fsssssssh</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Stylesheet `!important` will override inline styles unless they are `!important` too.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - You are correct. I could have sworn that was the case, and initially used a stylesheet with `!important`. I guess I simply made a typo haha ;) Updated now :)